# LAN Design Question with HP Procurve

Tags: local-area-network, network-design, hp-procurve

HP Procurve 2510G-24 x 2 Port (For Servers) and 2 x HP Procurve 2510-48 Port 10/100 (For Desktops).

Topology is like :

Patching is terminated on 2nd floor and the servers are located on the 1st Floor. Basically the servers are connected on the wall sockets (rj-45 outlet) on 1st Floor.

We need more ports downstairs, so we are planning to install ONE 2510G-24Port downstairs and One upstairs so that we can connect these two switches with some sort of port bundle / trunk so we get more throughput.

I am planning to connect the switch(24Port 2510G) to the wall socket 1 and 2, bundle two ports on the switch as 1 (so 2Gb pipe) and then do the same upstairs, so we get a 2Gb trunk between these two switches.

how would I bundle two ports together on each switch and make them appear as ONE for more speed?

we don't need vlans.
we will then configure the two 2510-48Port 10/100 switches with our desktop lan and one cable from 2510-48 to the server switch upstairs (2nd floor).

can I bundle up 4 ports on these two procurve, so 4Gb throughput ?

Also LACP and trunking - is this the same thing or two different things and when would i want to use LACP ?

would you have any recommendations as I am going to connect two switches together, one downstairs (where the servers are) and one upstairs (where the patch termination is)

Any thoughts on this ? I am new to Procurve but they seem quite feature rich. these are Layer 2 switches managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trunking will work well.  As noted, every compmnay has a different name. First time I ran into this there was no manual and no web access at the site.  One call to HP got me to a tech within minutes and we had the trunks up in 10 minutes or less.

Comment: You don't describe the method the HP techs used, nor whether Trunking or LACP was used, nor why.

Answer (score 1):

You 'bundle' them using LACP (known as a lot of things - "Ethernet bonding, NIC teaming, Trunking, port channel, link bundling, EtherChannel, Multi-Link Trunking (MLT), NIC bonding, network bonding" etc).

Trunking is a different but often linked technology where multiple VLANs are transmitted over a single connection, or LACP-linked 'bundle' of connections.

In terms of recommendations, at the very least I would create a single VLAN - this way you can more seamlessly introduce new VLANs in the future. The use of a pair of links from switch to switch makes sense, for failover support as much as increased performance.

Not totally clear how you want to link things though, maybe you could reword or create an image to embed? that would help I thing.

As for 4-way LACP 'bundles' - they are often supported but let's figure out more clearly what you're trying to do first before we get into that ok.

Comment: Hi Chopper3,

Thank you for your reply : I will embed a diagram this evening or earlier if I could. Please have a look back here again - will be grateful.

#config
#trunk 1, 2 trk1 trunk

will the above commands create a trunk with lacp or would I have to create lacp separately ?

Basically as we require more ports where the servers are, we are introducing a switch (2510G-24) and connect that switch to the second 2510G 24 Port switch where the patch is i.e. upstairs ;

I was thinking to connect say port 1,2,3,4 on both of the switches and create a trunk / lacp ?

Will get the diagram soon.

Comment: I'm a Cisco guy rather than a Procurve guy but there are lots of procurve guys on this site, that said I'd crack open the manuals and see if you can figure it out yourself, it'll be more rewarding and you'll learn it better if you can manage it yourself :)

Comment: "No intervening, non-trunking devices are allowed. It is important to
note that ports on both ends of a port trunk group must have the same mode (speed and duplex) and flow control settings"

Hi Chopper, Just read the above in HP Manual. As I would be connecting one switch to the wall sockets and then in-turn the second switch will be connected to the appropriate ports upstairs ;
does this mean we can't do trunking? :-)

Comment: LACP = trunking in HP talk.

Comment: Trunking in Cisco lingo means putting multiple VLANs on one port (group).

Comment: Hi Antoine,
Do you think I would be able to trunk the ports together given the topology ? as it says no intervening, non trunking devices are allowed ? I will connect one switch to the wall sockets and the other switch to the patch to form this bundle ?
Thanks

Comment: According to the HP 1800-24G manuals and help, trunking seems to match what @pfo said: multiple VLANs on one wire. LACP bundles wires. However - I'm still trying to understand this myself.

Comment: @AntoineBenkemoun: The configuration page for the HP Procurve 1800-24G permits LACP _or_ Trunks: they are different things.

Comment: @David yes indeed but it's not necessarily the same thing in HP or Cisco talk.